# How to put 2 charts next to each other

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, chart.js

I have two pie-charts and I am wondering how to locate two charts on the same line in vue.js. I have googled a bit but couldn't do it anyway.

Code:

```
<div id="block_container">
  <div v-if="data !== undefined">
    <div :id="chart1">
      <pie-chart
        :options="options"
        :data="data"
      ></pie-chart>
    </div>
    <div :id="chart2">
      <pie-chart
         :options="options"
         :data="data"
      ></pie-chart>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
  #block_container {
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single `div` `<div v-if="data !== undefined">` inside the `div` with the id `#block_container` try rearranging the html structure or styling the inner `<div v-if="data !== undefined">`